Users are accessing each other's account in Codeigniter when I implement WAF
The application is built with CodeIgniter 3. With in a Big corp. there are several users accounts on same public IP. Now upon implementing the WAF (Web Application Firewall), weird behavior happened.
When the users logged into their own accounts but accessed another user's profile directly. Few users were on their mobile devices using different data networks.
I have no clue why this has started after waf added. Is there any settings with sessions? why the sessions are jumping up. Below mentioned are the sessions settings in config file.
Session are stored in DB.
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ciapp_session';

$config['sess_expiration'] = 32400; //7200;

$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update'] =60; // 300;

$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] =  TRUE;


$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';

$config['cookie_domain']    = '';

$config['cookie_path']      = '/';

$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE; //setting this to TRUE leading me to 429 error on user login/logout

$config['cookie_httponly']  = TRUE;


What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Do the cookies (containing the session ID) reach your application without problems? Does the WAF maybe implement a cache that does not distinguish between different users?

What WAF (Web Application Firewall) do you apply and where?

I have added DNS records on running application. nothing changes on application level. Just adding WAF by changing the A and Cname records to different IP and Value provided by WAF vendors it started appearing. And by removing WAF, it works normal.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please keep in mind that there's no version 3.2 of CodeIgniter, and the whole v3 branch is pretty outdated

the docs say: cookie_secure: Whether to create the session cookie only on encrypted (HTTPS) connections, which brings me to ask you to check your .htaccess file, which might provoke the error 429 (too many requests). Are you using http and only when WAF is on https?

@Vickel Thanks for the great clue, but http is no where, the application is on https. Would you please suggest how should be the .htaccess file and what amendments I should do in config file as well?

Please also answer the other questions from the comment section, and ad all clarifcation to your question by editing it
